# Unexpected Communication Issue with Alexa

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I created my Alexa skill as an AWS Lambda java app and used the HelloWorld example provided in the Alexa Skills Kit. I followed all the steps given on the Amazon site including all the steps given here [Alexa not finding my Skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125326/alexa-not-finding-my-skill). Since Amazon doesn't fully give instructions at this point to use Lambda with java I followed the steps given in this tutorial https://github.com/jjaquinta/EchoProofOfConcepts/tree/master/jo.echo.lambda which I found on the Amazon forums page. When I run the code in Lambda it accepts it but only shows this as the Execution result:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

And get the following log output for an Alexa start session request:

```
START RequestId: 1e8a753b-37a5-11e5-bad6-6df6c6d7bdc9
SpeechletLambda init
warn:No timestamp tolerance has been configured, disabling timestamp verification
SpeechletLambda done init
Handling request
0 [main] WARN com.amazon.speech.speechlet.authentication.ApplicationIdVerifier  - Application ID verification has been disabled, allowing request for application ID amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.[unique-value-here]
warn:Timestamp verification has been disabled, allowing request request5678 with timestamp null
error:Exception occurred in speechlet 
java.lang.NullPointerException
jo.echo.lambda.utils.SpeechletLambda.handleRequest(SpeechletLambda.java:119)
hello.HelloWorldLambda.handleRequest(HelloWorldLambda.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:494)
lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:832)
lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:223)
lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:56)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:93)
END RequestId: 1e8a753b-37a5-11e5-bad6-6df6c6d7bdc9
REPORT RequestId: 1e8a753b-37a5-11e5-bad6-6df6c6d7bdc9  Duration: 2231.45 ms        
Billed Duration: 2300 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB    Max Memory Used: 78 MB
```

When I try the Skill with the echo I got an "Unexpected Communication Issue": Request Identifier:amzn1.echo-api.request.173c5d6c-8e97-493c-9efd-beb88cffd82f there was a problem communicating with the requested application.

Has anyone run into the same problem? I figure it might have to do with my zip packaging, so does anyone know the right way to package it?

This is the code I used for HelloWorld https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DU_-kAOxnhEp_4Lsj6I_LzEN4Di6-4Gmk28OZgc80IA/pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the Alexa app to comletely work by copying the HelloWorldSpeechlet, HelloWorldLambda and SpeechletLambda  from here https://github.com/jjaquinta/EchoProofOfConcepts/tree/master/jo.echo.lambda (I also needed to remove all Overrides from the HelloWorldSpheechlet class). After that I just needed to follow the steps given here: [Alexa not finding my Skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125326/alexa-not-finding-my-skill)

Answer (score 1):

have you first resolved the null pointer exception?  Sorry if you had and I am stating the obvious.  Can you log data coming in on the request envelope?