# Hosting a custom skill to Alexa by implementing a web service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on developing a web service which is used to **Handling Requests Sent by Alexa** and respond  back with specific response in .net framework. The request body sent by Alexa to your service in JSON format like below :

```
{
  "version": "string",
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "string",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "string"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "string": {}
    },
    "user": {
      "userId": "string",
      "accessToken": "string"
    }
  },
  "context": {
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "string"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "string",
        "accessToken": "string"
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {
          "AudioPlayer": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "token": "string",
      "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
      "playerActivity": "string"
    }
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

and **Response Body Syntax** in Json format below:

```
{
  "version": "string",
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "string": object
  },
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "string",
      "text": "string",
      "ssml": "string"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "content": "string",
      "text": "string",
      "image": {
        "smallImageUrl": "string",
        "largeImageUrl": "string"
      }
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "string",
        "text": "string",
        "ssml": "string"
      }
    },
    "directives": [
      {
        "type": "string",
        "playBehavior": "string",
        "audioItem": {
          "stream": {
            "token": "string",
            "url": "string",
            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "shouldEndSession": boolean
  }
}
```

I researched on Amazon Developer Forum [Hosting a Custom Skill as a Web Service](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service) , [Handling Requests Sent by Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/handling-requests-sent-by-alexa)but  i am not able to achieve this thing and one thing  i am not using **Lambda** function i want to make a custom skill and my location is not in **North US**.

I got the Lib. from github [here](https://github.com/AreYouFreeBusy/AlexaSkillsKit.NET) and used in my web service but not able to sync with this library, anyone here to  give me a direction how can i do this or how can i started thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've just published a project that uses the same AlexaSkillsKit.NET package that you mention.  The goal is to help everyone create Alexa Custom Skills using .NET + Visual Studio that you can easily deploy to Azure.

https://github.com/tamhinsf/Azure4Alexa

There's a sample skill implementation that you can use as a pattern for your own Custom Skill.  It makes use of httpClient and the usual async patterns.

Just download and fire up Visual Studio to get started!

Comment: Hi @Tam, Thanks for the  response i have a question can i deployed at own IIS Remote Server instead of Azure, if yes then what file should i need to set as  a startup file/page thanks.

Comment: Hey there - I've implemented this project as a Web API, so there's no start page configured as you would have in an MVC project.   There's a static page in the project root called "default.htm" if you want to point users at something to intro your custom skill.

Comment: Hi @Tam thanks for the respond back, I have followed your instructions steps at https://github.com/tamhinsf/Azure4Alexa/blob/master/README.md  but got the error :  "There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 405 : Method Not Allowed "    any idea why this happened.

Comment: What happens when you go to https://yourserver/default.htm - does the Azure4Alexa static HTML page load up OK?

Comment: yeah its loaded default.htm but when i am trying to Enter Utterance in Test "is there a good service on the tube " then i got the Response :- "There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 405 : Method Not Allowed". The endpoint url is : https://myservername.com/alexa/  at this moment i really don't know why this happened please help me or share you id where i can tell you the whole process thanks.

Comment: @SanjeevSangral your endpoint should be myservername.com/api/alexa unless you've changed the default project configuration that I created. Could you change this setting in the Amazon/Alexa dashboard and see what happens?

Comment: I made this change but error changed "There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 404 : Not Found"

Comment: If i change the path myservername.com/api/alexa then i'm not able to launch default.htm page but in myservername.com/alexa am able, so what should i do??

Comment: Can I get you to sign up for Azure for free and deploy the project there? :)  Unfortunately, I can't see your IIS configuration, but you shouldn't be setting any sort of startup page as this is a WebAPI project.  I think you might have a mapping that's causing /api/alexa to misfire.

Comment: now myservername.com/api/alexa/default.htm works fine, but the response which returned HTTP 405 : Method Not Allowed

Comment: @SanjeevSangral - Could I suggest you start with a clean deployment?  Like I said, this is an Web API project and there's no default document.  It looks like your IIS config has introduced a mapping that's throwing off the API route/controller.  "default.htm" is served off of the root in my original product and the Alexa API endpoint lives at /api/alexa.

Comment: I have follow the following steps :

Comment: 1 - download the code from github and extract at particular location. 
2- Import the project or you can say that open the sol in visual studio 2015. 
3 - Update the value of AppId to be the "Application Id" in Azure4Alexa>Alexa>AlexaConstants.cs. 
4 - Build the project and rebuild as well, launch in chrome and default.htm page launched.

Comment: 5 - Now deployed the project on the server with required credentials like site name, Server, Username etc and after deployed default.htm page launched. 
6 - Copy the url without default.htm and the url looks like https://alexa.myservername.com/api/alexa/  enter into the endpoint location in Alexa Skill set.

Comment: 7 - Update the Intent Schema and Sample Utterances same the located in the file path: Azure4Alexa -> Alexa -> Registration. 
8 - enter the utterance and press the Ask Azure Button.

Comment: 9 - get the Json Request  and response : - There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 405 : Method Not Allowed. 
this is the whole process that i have followed now i am totally stuck at this moment.

Comment: "5 - Now deployed the project on the server with required credentials like site name, Server, Username etc and after deployed default.htm page launched."  - What is the URL to default.htm after you deploy?

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time that the last answer was written, plus the example which Azure4Alexa sample implements, uses deprecated base classes, for cases where you might want to use the 'context' part of your Alexa request, you would want to implement `SpeechletBase, ISpeechWithContext` in your final Speechlet class.

To be honest, I know the README.md on [AlexaSkillsKit.net](https://github.com/AreYouFreeBusy/AlexaSkillsKit.NET) is very dense, but if you do give it some time, and go through the AlexaSkillsKit.Sample project, and go through the definitions of the implemented base classes, you will understand the request handling through and through.

Let me also take this opportunity to breakdown how I understand the classes and their structures:

`SampleSessionSpeechlet` Class - Is just the final class that Logs your request, and implements the `ISpecchletWithContext`(which mandates the implementation of `OnSessionStarted()`, `OnLaunch()`, `OnIntent()` & `OnSessionEnded()`) these four functions are basically handlers of all the requests that Alexa can send to your Web Service.

`SpecchletBase` Class - Basically Wraps around the `SpeechletService` Class which actually does the all heavy lifting.

`SpeechletService` Class - You basically call its `GetResponseAsync()`(which the `SpeechletSerive`'s `GetResponse()` wraps) which takes the passed Alexa Request, parses it into a cute little dataClass called `SpeechletRequestEnvelope`, does session management, passes the `SpeechletRequestEnvelope` to your your implementation of the `OnSessionStarted()`, `OnLaunch()`, `OnIntent()` or `OnSessionEnded()` methods, gets your returned objects and Returns your Alexa Response as a class called the `SpeechletResponseEnvelope`

Hope that helps with some quick implementation, but I highly recommend going through the Lib directory and understand how things work. And who knows? Contribute!